# How can I make it DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
if condition1
   ModelName.named_scope1(parameter).named_scope2.named_scope3(parameter).named_scope4
elsif condition2
   ModelName.named_scope1(parameter).named_scope2.named_scope3(parameter).named_scope5
elsif condition3
   ModelName.named_scope1(parameter).named_scope2.named_scope3(parameter).named_scope6
elsif 
   ModelName.named_scope1(parameter).named_scope2.named_scope3(parameter).named_scope7
end
```

To solve the above issue I have written it something like this but it fires two queries.

```
values = ModelName.named_scope1(parameter).named_scope2.named_scope3(parameter)

if condition1
   values.named_scope4
elsif condition2
   values.named_scope5
elsif condition3
   values.named_scope6
elsif 
   values.named_scope7
end
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Did you check in the logs for the two queries? Scopes shouldn't fire a query until they are evaluated (unless you're using rails 2, which I don't know anything about).

Answer (score 6):

Your first and second examples do exactly the same thing, so the original implementation must have also been sending two queries.  I think your pseudo-code is a little too generic to comment further, but generally when I have lists of if..elsif..else conditions (or long case..when's for that matter), I try to consider if I could use a lookup table (just a Hash) instead.  It may not directly apply to your example, however.

So instead of something like this:

```
case value
  when "one"
    obj.do_something(1, 2, 3)
  when "two"
    obj.do_something(4, 5, 6)
  when "three"
    ...
end
```

Re-think it as:

```
args_map = {
  "one"   => [1, 2, 3],
  "two"   => [4, 5, 6],
  "three" => ...
}

obj.do_something(*args_map[value])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [build dynamic scopes](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html) although without knowing exactly how you're determining scope selection criteria it's tough to say *where* the dynamic scope code might belong, or if the obvious solution (yours) might be more clear.